# ReactJS adds display:none on its own?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reactjs

I have a ReactJS app running with React-Router and several other packages on NodeJS. I've been making some changes on the code and suddenly one of my pages (one, not all of them) started acting weird. It just adds a `display:none` to the inline style of the main component.

On my code it's like this:
[image]

On inspector appears like this:
[image]

I'm completely lost. I don't have any jQuery messing directly with this component or anything, it just appears there.

The end result is as expected: the code runs just like it should, and the components are rendered, it just adds the annoying `display:none` there on its own, leaving the user with a black screen. If I turn it off, it shows me the page normally.

Any tips?

EDIT: As a test, I enclosed that `<div>` inside another one, wihtout any classes or inline styles, and it added an entire `style="display: none` to the empty `<div>` right below the "root". I'm so clueless at the moment.

EDIT 2: **It is not happening anymore!** However, all I did was change some conditions for the render method. I had a

```
if (boolean) { 
  return (
    <div id={mainDashboard}</div>
  );
} else {
  return (
    <div/>
  );
}
```

And changed it to a single `return` call, and used an Elvis operator instead. And it started working, no more misteriously added CSS.

Why? Does React handle this "conditional rendering" badly? Or did I just use it the wrong way?

Comment: Why do you give the div an id of `mainDashboard`? The html id property should be unique for the entire document and your component just assumes that how it's used it won't create duplicate id's. That is why you should not use html id property in components.

Comment: It would be nice to create a sandbox with same issue. Other than that it could be an extension, third party library or high order component. In chrome you can debug attr changes for each dom element. f12 -> Inspect ->  Right click to 'container-fluid' -> Break on -> attr changes. With this you can check if it is an event, extension or third library.

Comment: @HMR I added it to change the background via CSS. I deleted it to check your suggestion, it behaves the same ... wth ...

Comment: I am facing the same issue with react-router-dom.
When I do `history.push({search: newSearchParams})` it momentarily adds `style="display: none !important"` to the div outside of `<Switch>` component.
On break on attr change I see `hideInstance()` function from `react-dom.development.js` is being called.